# Create Multiple Shapefiles from GeoJSON

Tags: shapefile, geojson, ogr2ogr

I am attempting to convert a GeoJSON Feature Collection into multiple shapefiles. The shapefile a feature ends up in depends on a specific property of the GeoJSON, `layer_id`.

My desired output is a single zipped file, containing all the different shapefile folders.

So far I have converted GeoJSON with uniform `layer_id` to a single shapefile, using the ogr2ogr npm module. The output of the ogr2ogr command is a zipped shapefile.

I would like to either:

1. Learn how to designate a property for ogr2ogr to "group by" when
   creating a shapefile, creating multiple shapefiles
2. Learn how to create unzipped shapefiles with ogr2ogr, which I can then compress into a single zip

Comment: Unzipped  shapefile is the default https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/shapefile.html and creation of zip should require using .shz or .shp.zip as the name of the output.

Comment: @user30184 ah, thanks! It looks like the npm module adds the automatic zipping functionality then. I'll see what I can do about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike the ogr2ogr command line tool, the ogr2ogr npm module automatically zips shapefiles.

I forked the library and updated the 'ESRI Shapefile' entry in `drivers.json`, so that the `output` property has a value of `""`. This stops the npm module from zipping the directory, and the output is the shapefile directory.